# Read lines that do not begin with ]dos

Tags: r

I have to import a csv file with thousands of lines. In this file, the header appears several times. This header begins with the following four characters: `]dos`. I would like to readlines excluding the lines beginning with `]dos`.

The file looks like

```
N[ dos  Date dos    Heure Dos   Nom du patient  ex pat
N[ dos  Date dos    Heure Dos   Nom du patient  ex pat
7061283778  02-03-17    12h54   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA          02-03-17
7061283777  02-03-17    12h54   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             03-03-17
7061283790  02-03-17    12h54   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             02-03-17
7061283779  02-03-17    12h55   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA              02-03-17
7061300309  02-03-17    12h55   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             02-03-17
7061294068  02-03-17    12h56   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             03-03-17
7061283782  02-03-17    12h56   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA              02-03-17
N[ dos  Date dos    Heure Dos   Nom du patient  ex pat
7061283781  02-03-17    12h56   Mlle MONTALDO JIMENA            02-03-17
7061300311  02-03-17    12h57   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             02-03-17
```

As you can see the header appears three times.

---

I've the approach posted by @Jaap, but I think that the file is really dirty, in the sense that:

- it is a csv file but with separator ; instead of , (because it is French).
- several columns have empty values.
- Perhaps there are even unknown characters (not sure).

I got the following error message:

> df <- read.table(text = txt, header =FALSE)
>   Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     line 1 did not have 44 elements
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   closing unused connection 3 (extraction.csv)

I have to prepare a program in R that would be used by someone who knows nothing about programming or data analysis. This person will use regularly the program in order to get some results from the data. This person will not be able to clean that data by himself.

This is how the file looks like if you open it with Excel:

[image: how the file looks like if you open it with Excel]

Comment: hey, does your fix require that this be done in R? If you're only going to be doing analysis on this one file, it might be faster and easier to do this operation with Notepad or Notepad++.

Comment: It's pretty simple to fix from the command line: `grep ^[^N] file.txt > file2.txt` or `grep -v ^N file.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: With regard to the error: does using `df <- read.table(text = txt, sep = ';', header = FALSE)` help?

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem based on my answer and above comment?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the example data, I suppose you want to exclude lines that start with `N[ dos`.

You can get this data in a dataframe in several steps:

1. Read the datafile with `readLines`. (because I don't have the file, I've used a `textConnection`; but you could use it as follows: `readLines('name_of_your_file.txt')` to read in the text)
2. Remove the lines that start with `N[ dos` with the `grepl`-function.
3. Read the remaining text with `read.table`.

Complete code:

```
txtcon <- textConnection('N[ dos  Date dos    Heure Dos   Nom du patient  ex pat
N[ dos  Date dos    Heure Dos   Nom du patient  ex pat
7061283778  02-03-17    12h54   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA          02-03-17
7061283777  02-03-17    12h54   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             03-03-17
7061283790  02-03-17    12h54   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             02-03-17
7061283779  02-03-17    12h55   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA              02-03-17
7061300309  02-03-17    12h55   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             02-03-17
7061294068  02-03-17    12h56   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             03-03-17
7061283782  02-03-17    12h56   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA              02-03-17
N[ dos  Date dos    Heure Dos   Nom du patient  ex pat
7061283781  02-03-17    12h56   Mlle MONTALDO JIMENA            02-03-17
7061300311  02-03-17    12h57   Mme MONTALDO JIMENA             02-03-17')

txt <- readLines(txtcon)

txt <- txt[!grepl(pattern = '^N\\[ dos', txt)]

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = FALSE)
```

This results in the following dataframe:

```
> df
          V1       V2    V3   V4       V5     V6       V7
1 7061283778 02-03-17 12h54   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA 02-03-17
2 7061283777 02-03-17 12h54  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA 03-03-17
3 7061283790 02-03-17 12h54  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA 02-03-17
4 7061283779 02-03-17 12h55   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA 02-03-17
5 7061300309 02-03-17 12h55  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA 02-03-17
6 7061294068 02-03-17 12h56  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA 03-03-17
7 7061283782 02-03-17 12h56   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA 02-03-17
8 7061283781 02-03-17 12h56 Mlle MONTALDO JIMENA 02-03-17
9 7061300311 02-03-17 12h57  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA 02-03-17
```

---

Looking at the resulting dataframe, I suppose you want some of the columns together in one column. A possible approach could be:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = df$V1, 
                  datetime1 = strptime(paste(df$V2, df$V3), '%d-%m-%y %Hh%M'),
                  datetime2 = as.Date(df$V7, '%d-%m-%y'),
                  name = paste(df$V4, df$V5, df$V6))
```

whicht results in:

```
> df2
          id           datetime1  datetime2                 name
1 7061283778 2017-03-02 12:54:00 2017-03-02   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA
2 7061283777 2017-03-02 12:54:00 2017-03-03  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA
3 7061283790 2017-03-02 12:54:00 2017-03-02  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA
4 7061283779 2017-03-02 12:55:00 2017-03-02   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA
5 7061300309 2017-03-02 12:55:00 2017-03-02  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA
6 7061294068 2017-03-02 12:56:00 2017-03-03  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA
7 7061283782 2017-03-02 12:56:00 2017-03-02   Mr MONTALDO JIMENA
8 7061283781 2017-03-02 12:56:00 2017-03-02 Mlle MONTALDO JIMENA
9 7061300311 2017-03-02 12:57:00 2017-03-02  Mme MONTALDO JIMENA
```

Comment: or `txt[grep(pattern = '^N\\[ dos', txt, invert=TRUE)]`